# STL size_type(-1) vs size_t(-1)

Tags: c++, stl

In C++ STL implementation, I often see this code block:

```
size_type max_size() const {
    return size_type(-1);
}
```

I understand that it works when size_type is size_t. what is the purpose of adding a indirect level here? I.e. why not use `size_t(-1)` directly in `max_size()`?

is there any specification that says (size_type(-1)) should evaluate to the maximum object size on a platform)...

Comment: Because `size_type` is not really required to be `size_t`.

Comment: Is there any specification about what is "size type"?  Obviously "int" is not a size type.

Comment: @LeonLi: In a container `size_type` is borrowed from the allocator, that is the mechanism that handles the memory, sizes... In the default allocator `size_type` is defined to be `size_t`, but if you provide your own allocator for the container that need not be the case.